# Set the value of a drop down box on load

Tags: vb.net, combobox

If you look at the source code for the html you can see the combobox has an id. However when i run a loop through all hte elements on the page in vb.net it comes up as a blank instead of the id thats clearly defined. I'm thinking it has something to do with the javascript giving it a dynamic id. Anyway. I need to set this box after the page has loaded in a webbrowser object. Please help. Its driving me crazy!

```
<input type="hidden" name="wlw-select_key:{actionForm.dobMonth}OldValue" value="true">"
<select name="wlw-select_key:{actionForm.dobMonth}" id="dobMonth" class="dobMonth"><option" value="">Month</option>
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option></select>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript"> 
<!--
netui_tagIdNameMap.dobMonth="wlw-select_key:{actionForm.dobMonth}"
-->
</script>
```

****My Source Code Attemps ******
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("dobMonth").SetAttribute("selectedtext", "March") - dosent work

```
    Dim el As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.All("wlw-select_key:{actionForm.dobMonth}")
    Dim elCol As HtmlElementCollection = el.GetElementsByTagName("option")
    Dim X As Integer = 0
    For Each op As HtmlElement In elCol
        If op.InnerText = "March?" Then
            el.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", X.ToString())
            Exit For
        End If
        X += 1
    Next
```

- that didnt work either

So i'm really out of options. Any ideas. I did some research on the javascript reference but didnt turn out much useful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: one thing wrong with the above code is you're checking for "March?" whereas the text is simply "March" without the question mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I remember, the name and id attributes are limited in the characters they can contain. curly-braces are probably not allowed. not sure if that's your problem or not, but it's the first thing that popped into mind... I'll look into it some more.

[much later...]
OK, this works, but I hacked out a bunch of stuff, and it may not be quite what you're looking for:

```
<select name="dobMonth" id="dobMonth" class="dobMonth"><option value="">Month</option>
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("dobMonth").selectedIndex = 3;
</script>
```

You had a stray double-quote in your first option tag, which may have been part of the problem. But fixing that didn't allow the vbscript to work in my browser. I haven't done VBscript since the mid-90s so I switched to javascript. In any case it ought to give you a basis for further development, I hope!

[later]
This code will set the option by text string. I tested under Firefox, it ought to work in IE also:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setSelected(month) {
 var select = document.getElementById("dobMonth");
 var options = select.getElementsByTagName("option");
 for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  if (options[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue == month) {
   select.selectedIndex = i;
   break;
  }
 }
}
setSelected("March");
</script>
```

Comment: that would work but I dont have the ability to modify the html

Comment: you may not need to modify the HTML. what happens when you try the javascript I provided?

Comment: I just tried using your original HTML, and it set the value to April; change selectedIndex to 2 for March.